# JavaFX Scene Builder -- Drag-And-Drop Between Parent Nodes

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am using FXML alongside Scene Builder to develop a very simple interface. Below, the first image represents the layout hierarchy. The second image displays a text area when the button is pressed.

The action event method instantiates a new text area and assigns it to the first flow pane (left to right). My goal is to drag and drop each text area to any of the other flow panes.

My first attempt was to use assign use an Event handler to detect MOUSE_PRESSED: `textArea.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.DRAG_DETECTED, e-> handle(e));`

When I got to setting up the handle method, things got confusing. For example, should I included the other various MouseEvent's, such as MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET, MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET? And how is the MOUSE_RELEASED handle composed?

I started to look at Dragboard and Clipboard, and didn't find much luck there either. Clipboard only seemed capable of handling string values, or in a roundabout sort of way, images. I'm sure there is a simple answer to my predicament, as it clearly shows I'm wondering around in uncharted territory.

I've read through several "textbook" resources, but they all address the movement of objects that are constructed at runtime, and most conform to what appear to be generic or straightforward examples.

**NOTE** 
I apologize for the images, I realize it isn't quite clear. There are 5 flow panes distributed across the grid pane. I will try to edit and update it shortly.

[image: initial interface hierarchy]
[image: after button is pressed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I understand you're trying to drag and drop `TextAreas` to different `FlowPanes`. You can achieve this by using `DragEvents`, not `MouseEvents`. Here's an example:

Considering a simple layout like yours, only taking the `TextArea` and two `FlowPanes` into account, we'd have the following fields:

```
@FXML
private TextArea textArea;

@FXML
private FlowPane flowPane1;

@FXML
private FlowPane flowPane2;
```

At the start, `textArea` is positioned on `flowPane1`, on the left side of the `GridLayout`.

[image: TextArea on left grid]

We'd like to drag and drop ´textArea´ to the right `flowPane`. So first, we have to tell the `textArea` it should be draggable. In this case, moving. You can implement it in different ways, but here I'll show you to just move the existing `TextArea` to the other `FlowPane`. Another method would be just re-creating one with the text on it.

```
textArea.setOnDragDetected((MouseEvent event) -> {
    //We want the textArea to be dragged. Could also be copied.
    Dragboard db = textArea.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

    // Put a string on a dragboard as an identifier
    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    content.putString(textArea.getId());
    db.setContent(content);

    //Consume the event
    event.consume();
});
```

Then, we'd like `flowPane2` to accept the `textArea` when it's being dragged to. So first, we tell it to accept the textArea when it's being dragged over.

```
flowPane2.addEventHandler(DragEvent.DRAG_OVER, (DragEvent event) -> {
    if (event.getGestureSource() != flowPane2
            && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
    }
    event.consume();
});
```

After we allowed it to be dragged, we do want it to actually do something and accept it when being dropped. So we add another handler to accept the dropped `textArea`.

```
flowPane2.addEventHandler(DragEvent.DRAG_DROPPED, (DragEvent event) -> {
    //Get the dragboard back
    Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
    boolean success = false;
    //Could have some more thorough checks of course.
    if (db.hasString()) {
        //Get the textarea and place it into flowPane2 instead
        flowPane2.getChildren().add(textArea);
        success = true;
    }
    //Complete and consume the event.
    event.setDropCompleted(success);
    event.consume();
});
```

The result, the `textArea` can be moved from `flowPane1` to `flowPane2`. Not vice versa, but this'll get you going!

[image: Dragged textArea]

Comment: I think I have a much clearer understanding of this after reading your response, so thank you! Could you explain where the method/eventHandlers need to be located?

Comment: That probably depends on where you create them. Since you create your textArea through a button, you could probably wire up the eventHandler right there. In this example, I just used `initialize(URL, ResourceBundle)` which is inherited by `Initializable` in the `Controller`. So it's wired up when it's initialized.